# Connecting an external debugger for browser extension development

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension, webstorm, browser-extension

I'm trying to figure out how to properly attach an external debugger from, say WebStorm or vs-code to debug a browser extension.

**How my ideal workflow would look like:**
I launch an extension in dev-mode with https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext and then can attach debugger to that browser instance, see break-points/etc.

#### What I've tried

- Configure https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-debugger.html specifying a URL on which my extension operates.
- Add a break-point to a content-script
- After browser is started by debug process - load my extension from disk & reload the page

**Expected:** debugger stops at a break point
**Actual:** page loads without interruption (or sometimes debugger stops at a random code not from my extension  )

I've also tried setting the breakpoint for a background script, which didn't seem to have any effect either.

---

**Misc**

- For content-script WebStorm seems to indicate that break-points are not in a valid state [image]
- Background script breakpoint is, not that it helps [image]
- Code is bundled with Parcel with source-maps enabled
- Browser is Chrome 99.0.4844.51 (FF debugging does not seem to be supported)
- System: macOS 12.2

Comment: You need to ensure the browser is started with --remote-debugging-port=12345 and then attach your IDE to this port number.

Comment: WebStorm already starts the browser with debug port enabled when I use the debug configuration. I've performed actions described in that browser instance